# How to alter Entity Framework column to jsonb with USING?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, jsonb

Trying to alter a column from a text field to a jsonb field using Entity Framework code-first migrations.

The column mostly has json objects stored as text but some are not valid json. When trying to run the migration it throws the error:

> Exception: 42804: column "Message" cannot be cast automatically to type jsonb

Code:

```
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
    name: "Message",
    schema: "database",
    table: "ScheduledEvent",
    type: "jsonb",
    nullable: false,
    oldClrType: typeof(string),
    oldType: "text");
```

In this thread, https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/144, they have the same issue and say the solution was to add a `USING` clause.

How can I update the code first EF model to add a `USING` clause in the migration?

Comment: Use [raw SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#adding-raw-sql)

Comment: That's what I am trying to avoid. I am asking if there is a code first approach without having to insert raw SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Change your migration file like below and update the migration. It will work!!!

```html
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
    name: "Message",
    schema: "database",
    table: "ScheduledEvent",
    type: "jsonb USING \"Message\"::jsonb",
    nullable: false,
    oldClrType: typeof(string),
    oldType: "text");
```